# Will current versions of Google reCaptcha work when new versions are released?

Tags: recaptcha

We are launching v3 recaptcha on our site, and wanted to know if newer versions of v3 are released will:

- Will the version in use continue to work before upgrading
- Will we be notified and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have no idea.